# Where do compiler flags come from when using qmake?

Tags: qmake

I have a qmake project in which I cannot debug because *something* adds `-O2 -g` to the end of the compiler flags in debug mode, overriding all my debug and optimization flags. I have greped the whole project for `-O2` and there is none (I removed the one I had for release). Deleting the build folder and running qmake again didn't help. I'm trying to track down what adds compiler flags, but I'm missing something.

Known things that can add compiler flags:

- `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` - Adds flags as given in all builds.
- `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG` - Adds flags as given in debug builds.
- `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE` - Adds flags as given in release builds.
- `CONFIG` - Adds flags that are difficult to trace. `CONFIG += strict_c++` and `CONFIG += c++17` managed to not have my `-std=c++17` overwritten, but I can't tell what other flags that adds. Also the `qmake` call contains `CONFIG+=debug` which may or may not add other flags. I can't tell from [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config).
- `mkspec` - In projects->build it lists the effective qmake call which includes for example `-spec linux-g++` which I think includes `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf` which includes more files which add platform-dependent flags. Removing the spec flag didn't remove the undesired `-O2` flag though. Also it works for other projects, so it's probably not the culprit.
- `TEMPLATE` - Specifies how the project is organized. Normally it's just `APP`, but this one uses `subdirs` which may override flags as all sub projects need to have the same flags.

An ideal answer would list all ways to add compiler flags, in which order they are added, an explanation how to check what flags they add and how to change them.

Answer (score 1):

What qmake does it simply produces a makefile. A generated Makefile only uses compiler flags from `CXXFLAGS` (plus `DEFINES`) and `INCPATH` make variables, unless you have some handcrafted rules. It is clearly viewable from a generated makefile.

And these make variables come directly from qmake vars, such as `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`, `DEFINES` and `INCLUDEPATH`. (This is done internally in qmake source code; well, actually the stuff could be more complicated on some platforms, so refer to qmake source code too).

Now, `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` is just a qmake's variable. So, in principle, it can be modified at any line of any qmake script. Given that these scripts depend on OS/arch/compiler/Qt build options/App options etc. your expectations of "an ideal answer" are overstretched too far.

But, roughly speaking, qmake sources its scripts in the following order (hint: see full dependency list in a generated makefile):

```
features/spec_pre.prf
<QMAKE-SPEC>/qmake.conf (usually includes features/qt_config.prf and a ton of Qt-related stuff)
features/spec_post.prf
features/default_pre.prf
<user project>
features/default_post.prf
all features/xxx.prf according to the final CONFIG value (note: order reversed!)
```

So if you miss some flag in your project, it probably originates either from `default_post.prf` (like release flags for release build), or from `CONFIG` (i.e. `features/xxx.prf`).

Comment: Unfortunately what you write is wishful thinking and not reality. For example qmake clearly uses `CXXFLAGS_DEBUG` as well. Also no, the flags don't all get collected in the makefile because generating the makefile and using `grep -nrw -e "-O2" .`  finds no results, so the flags come from outside the makefile or are not there in plaintext. I even manually started `make` to make sure there are no weird environment variables set and the `-O2` still appears.

Comment: @nwp There's no such variable `CXXFLAGS_DEBUG`. Qmake internal variables are (mostly) prefixed with `QMAKE_`. You seem to confuse qmake variables and make variables.